# Побитно записать в файл зашифрованный алгоритмом Хаффмана код

Tags: алгоритм, сжатие, c++

Привет, ХэшКод.
Я написал алгоритм Хаффмана, построил дерево, получил новые коды символов, но никак не могу записать их побитово в файл.
Имеется массив(string) единиц и нулей, в интернете нашел код:

```
ofstream fout("out.txt", ios::out | ios::binary);
for each(char s in bnr)
{
    buf = buf | s << (7 - count);
    count++;
    if (count == 8)
    {
        count = 0;
        fout << buf; 
        cout << buf;
        buf = 0;
    }
}
```

Но, он не работает, помогите пожалуйста и, по возможности, объясните на примере как правильно выполнять побитовые операции.
Заранее спасибо!

UPD:
Если кому нужно

```
ofstream fout("outcod.bin", ios::out | ios::binary);
unsigned char buf = 0;
int count = 0 , global_counter=0;
for each(unsigned char s in bnr)
{
    buf = buf | (s & 1) << (7 - count);
    count++;
    global_counter++;
    if (count == 8)
    {
        count = 0;
        fout << buf; 
        buf = 0;
    }
}
if (count>0)
{
    fout << buf;
}
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что у Вас байты в `bnr` это *двоичные* нули и единицы?

(а также, что `buf` и `count` обнулены перед циклом)

Comment: Нет конечно) bnr - строка char, фишка в том чтобы так подогнать биты(8 бит) в buf чтобы их последовательность была такая же как в bnr(соответственное тоже 8 символов)
buf и count обнулены(забыл дописать)

Comment: Вы хотите текстовый файл из 0 и 1, или же бинарный?

Answer (score 1):

Опять до конца не понял.

В `s` у Вас все 8 бит значащие или один бит или s = '1' или '0' т.е. символы?

Если все значащие, то просто пишите `s` в файл (и никакой цикл с  `buf` не нужен).

Если s это ASCII код цифр 0, 1, то

```
    buf = buf | ((s - '0') << (7 - count));
```